# Copying preceding values in a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a question

Say, I have a couple of columns and one column in a csv file containing these values:

0
1
2
1
1
2
3
2
66
2
0
1
2
66

And I have a newly created log csv file.

My goal is to copy the 3 values preceding value 66 within in a column to the newly created csv file.
I tried many different things. 
The last thing I tried is the 'enumerate' option, but this option also does not take the preceding 3 values into account

My Code is

import csv
import sys
import datetime

## Writes a complete line to the log file and moves to the next line of the log file

def log_write_line(*args):

```
# Make the global log_file variable accessible from this function using the 'global' keyword
global log_file

# Convert the parameters into a list of parameters
#args = ['my_block_nr', 'my_trial_nr',1]
args = list(args)

# Need to make sure that every single items in the 'args' list is of the variable type 'string'
# In order for the generic 'join' method below to work. It accepts strings, not integers.
# therefore 'list comprehensions' is necessary.

# Read the line below as: 'args' becomes a list of every item 'a' converted to a string
args = [str(a) for a in args]


# Join those parameters together to a single comma-separated line.
# At the end of these joined values, add a new line ("\n") character to move to the next line
# in my log file.

log_line = ','.join(args) + "\n"
print 'log line:', log_line

# Actually write the composed log line to the log file
log_file.write(log_line)

# Flush the data written to the file directly to the disk
log_file.flush()
```

## Writes a single value to the log file, followed by a comma- choose sooner

def log_write_value(value):

```
# Make the global log_file variable accessible from this function using the 'global' keyword
global log_file

print 'log write value:', value, type(value)

log_file.write(str(value))
log_file.write(',')
log_file.flush()
```

## Moves the output of the log file to the next line

def log_write_newline():
    # Make the global log_file variable accessible from this function using the 'global' keyword

```
global log_file
log_file.write('\n')
log_file.flush()
```

## Open new Data file

global log_file

filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("experiment-%y%m%d_%H%M%S.csv")
log_file = open(filename, 'w+')

## Open Data file with thought probes

def open_data_thought_probes_plus_new_file():

```
f = open('DATA_File.csv','rU')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    ints = [row[0]]
    list(enumerate(ints, start = (-3)))
    print list
    log_write_value(list(enumerate(ints, start = 3)))
```

I would be highly thankful to any help. The big question for me is whether there is a code that takes the preceding 3 values before a fixed value into account? Or else you should best do it?

Thanks a lot!!
Tiber

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I think you were close with `enumerate`.  If you have a list `l`:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 66, 2, 0, 1, 2, 66]

for i,x in enumerate(l):
    if x == 66:
        print l[i-3:i] # access the list via indices, i
        #copy these values to log

>>>[2, 3, 2]
>>>[0, 1, 2]
```

Or using list comprehension, will return a list of lists:

```
[l[i-3:i] for i,x in enumerate(l) if x == 66]

>>>[[2, 3, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Unfortunately, both methods will return an empty list if `66` is one of the first 3 elements:

```
l = [0, 1, 66, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 66, 2, 0, 1, 2, 66]

for i,x in enumerate(l):
    if x == 66:
        print l[i-3:i]

>>[]
>>[2, 3, 2]
>>[0, 1, 2]
```